# call an API after setting item in localstorage

Tags: javascript, async-await, local-storage

I want to call an API only after setting a user token in `localstorage`.

```
  const loginSuccess = async (data)=>{
   setItemInLocalStorage("ACCESS_TOKEN", data?.access_token); // setting item in localstorage
   dispatch(actions.getUserDetail({ userId: loggedUser.Sid })); // calling API
  }
```

**setItemInLocalStorage** function :

```
function setItemInLocalStorage(key, value) {
    let localValue;
    if (typeof value === 'object') {
        localValue = JSON.stringify(value);
        localStorage.setItem(key, localValue);
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem(key, value);
    }
    if(key === "ACCESS_TOKEN") {
        ACCESS_TOKEN = value;
    }
}
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: you did this, what is the issue?, setting data to localStorage is sync operation, you will have your token in yours API call

Comment: Shouldn't your question rather be "Set localStorage item after API call has been resolved ?" (deduced from what I see of your implmentation). But anyway I don't understand, what isn't working ? Just one thing: seems like your `loginSuccess` callback doesn't need the `async` declaration since your not using `await` inside it.

Comment: @shutsman  and @Peterrabbit, Sorry. I thought `localstorage` is asynchronous. By the way, thanks.